# Ruby on rails Failed to precompile

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm learning to make a web-app for a week and I'm successful to run it locally,but can't push it to heroku master. I get the following error:

[image]

Comment: Did you run `heroku run rake db:migrate`? I need a bit more information in order to provide you with a solid answer. Such as what Heroku commands did you use and what does your Model look like etc.

Comment: let me have a try

Comment: First step to become a developer - "Learn to read the docs properly and you will never get the errors"

Comment: https://github.com/dongluofan/demo_app.git

Comment: It is my code..thanks very much

Answer (score 0):

https://www.codecademy.com/articles/deploy-rails-to-heroku
Follow the steps mention here to deploy at heroku.

Comment: @family no problem :)